# Use CellSelectionModel with autoEdit:true in SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

I have a SlickGrid on my site and have implemented some copy/paste functionality. This requires that I use the CellSelectionModel, which requires that I set autoEdit to false for the grid.

I want autoEdit to be true and still be able to use my selection model. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Isn't that counter-productive? autoEdit will change the column to the editor associated. You could however make that editor select-all text on focus, which might achieve the same as cell-selection.

Comment: I don't quite understand your point. autoEdit will change the column('s editor?) to the editor associated (with what)? I want to select cells on click and drag, but also start editing the currently selected cell if the user starts typing (autoEdit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have the copy/paste functionality with autoEdit true. I have it.

You can try it for yourself here: http://labs.nereo.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-excel-compatible-spreadsheet.html

Now, with a javascript console, write:

```
grid.setOptions({autoEdit:true})
```

You still can copy/paste.
It is more difficult to select a range of cells... (you can't have any active cell, without more development).

But, the short answer is, you can.

Comment: That didn't work for me. I see that it works on http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example-spreadsheet.html, but it doesn't at the link you gave or my own implementation.

Comment: It must work in the link I gave. Please run again the command I gave you and then this one: grid.getOptions(); and check if autoEdit was really set to true.
If it doesn't work in your code, must be another issue.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an oldie but in case anyone's still running in this issue... look for the following lines in CellExternalCopyManager.init() and remove them or comment them out. There's a comment above the code that explains why it's there but I can't reproduce that problem it describes when it's removed. I've been using this solution for years without anyone reporting any issues.

> cellSelectionModel.onSelectedRangesChanged.subscribe(function(e, args){
>           _grid.focus();
>         });

Comment: Removing these lines out in slick.cellexternalcopymanager.js worked like a charm for me. No issues with the focus issue they describe either. Thanks!